# couchbase docker port 8091 has 301 redirect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, couchbase

New to Couchbase, been using couchdb, but I think the Couchbase data model will work better for my purposes.

I've set up a docker-compose file that uses the couchbase:community image:

```
version: "3"
services:
  couchbase:
    container_name: couchbase
    image: couchbase:community
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8092:8092"
      - "8093:8093"
      - "8094:8094"
      - "11210:11210"
    networks:
      - cbtemp
    volumes:
      - ../demodbs/cbdir:/opt/couchbase/var

networks:
  cbtemp:
    external:
      name: cbtemp
```

(the cbtemp network is created beforehand so I can add a sync-gateway image separately)

It comes up fine and accessing localhost:8091 in chrome brings up the admin panel just fine.

But, if I try to 'curl http://localhost:8091', I get this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
  ...
The document has moved <a href="http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html>here<
  ...
```

If I curl the redirected url, I get an html page (with some angular stuff in it, no less - I'm presuming that's the admin page?)

If I 'curl http://localhost:8092', I get the expected response, but, of course, nothing wants to access couchbase on :8092

As an aside, bringing up the sync-gateway image accesses the :8091 url just fine and works as expected.

Not a deal-breaker (yet), but annoying.

Comment: Hi, is there a question in here? I read your post but I didn't understand what the expected situation is. By the way you can also mix ports and map host port 8091 to container port 8092 if needed. Also curl has the "-L" flag that follows redirects and will give you the same answer as Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accessing the root path when you go to just port 8091 with nothing else.  Anything accessing Couchbase functionality is going to add a path, so this will be dealt with by internal routing.  You can see those paths if you look at the REST api docs.

For whatever reason, they decided to host the admin UI off a base base starting with `/ui`.  Hence the redirect, as they're assuming that if you didn't supply any path you want the UI.

It's not correct that nothing wants to access Couchbase through port 8092, either.  Various services use different ports.  8092 is used for some forms of query and other purposes.  You can find out more about the different ports and why you need them open in the Couchbase docs.

Comment: just for the documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/install/install-ports.html